# Instagram api: how to get photos containing like?

Tags: instagram

in my application, i enter a user name and get his photo.
(To get photos, i use: https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/3/media/recent/?access_token = ...)
Request returns only 20 pictures, how to get all photos user?

I want to get photos of this user which contain his likes. 
How can this be done?

I have an idea to get all the pictures that have user and check each pictures does it have his like ?!
But I get only the data for the four member who delivered Like, although photo has 50 likes. (See the screenshot below). Why so ? How to fix it ?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a two step process:

1) Perform a GET request to /users/user-id/media/recent inorder to get the most recent media published by a user.

2) Then perform a second GET request to /media/media-id/likes in order to get a list of users who have liked this media.

At this point you can record all the media-id's which contain likes by the specific person you want.

Here is the API for instagram users:
http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/

Here is the API for instagram likes: 
http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/likes/

As for getting the entire history, I apologize but I'm unclear as to how to go about doing more than what they provide.

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Thank you for comment. I get photos and now i want to get a list of users who have liked this media. I use /media/media-id/likes like u said, how can i get media-id for this request ? And i want to use this request without access_token, i want to use user-id. Can i make it ?

Comment: hey, good to hear! When you perform a GET request to /users/user-id/media/recent you're going to get a data stream whose attribute is categorized by media-ids (you'll get JSON like {{..."id": "26621408"
}, "likes": {count: 7...}}). You're going to replace your second get request with the content in the "id". So now your second get request will look like GET media/26621408/likes. Some endpoints only require the client_id as explained here(http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/), however your second GET request requires an access token (http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/likes/)